# MemoryAppender PatternLayout not rendering?

Tags: c#, log4net

App.config looks like this:

```xml
<appender name="MemoryAppender" type="log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level - %message" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Code looks like this:

```
foreach (var ev in events)
{
   string msg = ev.RenderedMessage;
}
```

The string returned from `ev.RenderedMessage` is *just* the message, not the entire pattern. I've also tried using `WriteRenderedMessage` with a `StringWriter` and the result was the same. Is there a way to get the message with the pattern applied?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found it :)

```
var events = _ma.GetEvents();
string result = "";
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    foreach (var ev in events)
    {
        _ma.Layout.Format(writer, ev);
        writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    result = writer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: 1.I was looking for this solution for some time, care to share how (or where) did you manage to find it? 2.I suggest you use %n at the end of your conversion pattern (for new line), that way you can avoid the `writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);` and have a more generic code (if someone already has %n your current code will go down 2 lines every time).